# how to pass the file path in android

Tags: android

Hi all
i have java project for calculating bpm now trying convert in to android project.While i get the following error.
i have mh.mp3 file in res\raw folder. i need to pass the file name with path.
i need specify file path in  " player = new Player(new FileInputStream("res\raw\mh.mp3"), output);"
i tried the following also but did not work

player = new Player(new FileInputStream("R.raw.mh"), output);"

it shows error at the following line as IndexOutOfBound Exception at

text.setText("bpm is  "+processor.getBPM());

but in java it works well when send file name as command line argument.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

R.raw.mh isn't the filename; it's a resource ID. You should use [Resource.openRawResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29).

Please don't spam the same question multiple times. You posted the same question as [bpm calculation error in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684643/bpm-calculation-error-in-android) 20 minutes ago.

Comment: hii tried   
String fis = getResources().getResourceName(R.raw.mh);
player = new Player(new FileInputStream(fis), output);
i got the same error at the same line. i tried the following also but it fdoes not match with FileInputStream. i need to pass song file as FileInputStream's input. please help me. 
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mh);